# Unable to copy files in objective-c OSX to Application Support folder for another app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have tried various google searches that landed on examples here and none seem to work right for one of my specific copy routines.

I am attempting to have a backup and restore option for an outside program in a helper program I am designing.
I tried NSURL and associated array and loops to iterate through dir contents.
I have tried the escaped space in the path string and url.
I have also tried as the examples below show, to do just a raw file copy based on a path NSString.

Swift is not really an option for me so I am mainly trying to go the route of objective-c.

This section works:

```
- (void)backup
{
    NSString *userFiles = @"~/Library/Application Support/OutsideProgramHere/";
    userFiles = [userFiles stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSString *backup = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"backup"];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:userFiles toPath:backup error:nil];

    NSString *bothpaths = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copied\r\n\r\nUser Path:%@\r\n\r\n<to>\r\n\r\nBackup Path:%@", userFiles, backup];

    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setMessageText:bothpaths];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

The reverse does not:

```
- (void)restore
{
    NSString *userFiles = @"~/Library/";
    userFiles = [userFiles stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    userFiles = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Application Support/OutsideProgramHere",userFiles];
    NSString *backup = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"backup"];
    //backup = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", backup];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:backup toPath:userFiles error:nil];

    NSString *bothpaths = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copied\r\n\r\nBackup Path:%@\r\n\r\n<to>\r\n\r\nUser Path:%@", backup, userFiles];

    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setMessageText:bothpaths];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

As you can see I tried to mess with the path a little bit as well.
I originally created the path output message as a debug, but I think that will remain as a confirmation to the user on success.

It also is intentional that it saves backups to this program's package/resources folder.
The source folder will have files and folders inside it together that it should copy over recursively keeping structure in tact.

I am kinda at a loss as to how to go from here without drastically changing any other aspects of the code. I can see how this "may" duplicate questions asked before. But as I said, no other examples I have found work, and looking for only objective-c solutions.

Self discovered answer:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:userFiles error:nil];
```

before the copy works.

Comment: ok, right after posting this I discovered I had the source and destination wrong so I edited that here after seeing that also did not work. But I also discovered that if the OutsideProgram folder exists it refuses to copy. If I delete it then it copies.

Comment: Nothing like answering my own questions. Leaving this so someone else can be helped by it as well.

Comment: Your code relies on the App's wrapper being writable.  That generally isn't true and, in the best case, should **never** be true.   I.e. your code would fail on my system.

Comment: I was thinking that as well. But the Support folder is under user Library not system Library. Also the application this is a "helper" to writes and deletes all the time from same directory. (It is also a commercial application. I would hope? they did it correctly?)

Comment: The `backup` method is explicitly attempting to copy to a path that is in `mainBundle`'s `resourcePath`.  That is the issue I was pointing out.   Your fine in the folder under `Library`, though keep in mind that a fully sandboxed app should be restricted in where it can read and write (but I don't remember the details on OS X).

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean there. I don't have it too restricted. May just have it create it's own support folder. But I was trying to obscure the backup folder from view/direct edits.